# Why isn't this adding the class in the way I expect?

Tags: javascript, css, materialize

I've got a Meteor project and am using the Materialize UI. I wanted to change to look of the modals by adding a unique border around them so I found out what the Materialize class was for the modals and added some CSS

```
.materialize-modal {
padding: 1em;
border: 1em solid transparent;
background: linear-gradient(white, white) padding-box, repeating-linear-gradient(-45deg, red 0, red 12.5%, white 0, white 25%, #58a 0, #58a 37.5%, white 0, white 50%) 0 / 5em 5em;
}
```

But this, of course, changes all the modals. My intent is to only use this on some of them. So I thought that if I added a class when a modal is triggered (a modal where I don't want the special border), I could just add a class upon triggering:

```
$('.materialize-modal').addClass('plain');
```

and now with the CSS:

```
.materialize-modal:not(.plain) {
padding: 1em;
border: 1em solid transparent;
background: linear-gradient(white, white) padding-box, repeating-linear-gradient(-45deg, red 0, red 12.5%, white 0, white 25%, #58a 0, #58a 37.5%, white 0, white 50%) 0 / 5em 5em;
}
```

No luck here. I would guess that using 'addClass' isn't adding the class in the way I imagine; it's perhaps looking for the 'plain' class and trying to apply the CSS to it. The 'plain' class doesn't have any CSS associated with it. It's just there to prevent the borders on some of the modals with the thinking that the ':not' selector would see the added class. Any way to do this?

Comment: So the wrong `materialize-modal` element was getting the class?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Most likely, you have applied the Css class to the wrong element or jQuery can't find the element and that's why it hasn't been added to it.

Check that jQuery can find the element

```
console.log($('.materialize-modal').length); //If 0 then it can't find the element
```

If length is 0 you may need to call the code inside `setTimeout(function() {},0);`
If length is 1 and there is still an issue.

Use chrome Dev tools (f12) and inspect the modal to check the class is actually on the modal.

If the class is on the modal then the CSS is the issue, you perhaps need to change your css to:

```
.materialize-modal:not(.plain) .modal-dialog {
    padding: 1em;
    border: 1em solid transparent;
    background: linear-gradient(white, white) padding-box, repeating-linear-gradient(-45deg, red 0, red 12.5%, white 0, white 25%, #58a 0, #58a 37.5%, white 0, white 50%) 0 / 5em 5em;
  }
```

Comment: Thanks for your help. It appears jQuery can't find the element.

Comment: Ah. I found the problem. At the immediate time of trigger the modal isn't in the DOM yet. jQuery was looking for the class but it needed a slight delay to give the markup a little time to enter the DOM. A setTimeout of 10ms does the trick. In fact 10ms is more than enough.

Comment: You should really only use setTimeout(function() {},0); The only time to use anything other than 0 if you want an actual period of elapsed time before something executes (e.g an animation). When you call it with 0 you are putting that execution to the end of the stack. (Because Javascript is single threaded you code will execute once all other pending tasks are finished). Try 0 it should work fine

Comment: Have updated answer anyways, please accept if satisfactory :) Cheers!

Comment: Thanks. Interesting because I had tried 0 earlier (before your comment) and noticed that it still worked but set it to 10 anyway. Thanks so much for clarifying! Learn something every day.